# What is the performance difference between "a<=b" and "(a<b) OR (a==b)"?

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, performance

Also is `a<=b` similar in performance to `a<b` or is it two times. 
Consider these three scenarios:

```
     for (int i =0; i <= 10; i++) {
      // Some operations here
      }
```

```
     for (int i =0; (i < 10) OR (i == 10); i++) {
      // Some operations here
      }
```

```
     for (int i =0; i <10; i++) {
      // Some operations here
     }
```

How would you compare these three?

Comment: Did you mean `a==b`? `a=b` is a _very_ different operation.

Comment: The time complexity is not a measure of execution time.

Comment: Remember that the logical OR operator uses [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) in both Python and C++.

Comment: I recommend putting code readability above these considerations.

Comment: it depends the operation ... 
Is it a "while" or a "if" ?? etc.

Comment: Don't worry about stuff like this.  Any decent compiler will emit the same machine code.  When optimizing, first code it normally, then profile, **and then use that hard data** to find the slow spots and fix them.

Comment: Also remember that C++ have operator overloading, which could mean the two expressions could be *vastly* different. And considering this point and because you tagged both Python and C++, your question is to broad. Please pick *one* language.

Comment: See the updated question body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on programming language, hardware and compiler, but, if you are about C++ over common x86 CPU and compiler that can not optimize this statement, the difference is about assebmly code generation.

On Assembler level, comparison is subtraction with further flags check. `a <= b` may become something like that:

```
cmp eax, ebx
jle a_le_b
```

We suppose that variables are in registers already to simplify the example. You see, we need 2 instruction only.

`(a<b) | (a==b)` literally means this:

```
cmp eax, ebx
jl a_le_b
cmp eax, ebx
je a_le_b
```

Again, here I translated the C++ to assembler without any optimization, just "as is". If compiler has optimization enabled, it will most probably generate the same code for both statements.

Now, in C++ the operators may be overloaded. It means that `<=` (theoretically) can perform completely different operations of different cost that `<` and `=`. However, in practice usually `<=` will be implemented exactly like call to `<` followed by call to `==` or vice versa.

**Conclusion**: in practice, for optimized compiler on common processor type and semantically correct class that calls comparison operator, you will not have any observable difference. However, semantics of these 2 statements are not exactly the same, so theoretically it is even possible that `a <= b` will give different result from `a < b | a == b`.

Comment: If we talk about assembly code is ```jle``` more complex operation than ```jl```?

Comment: No, it is not. Any conditional jump instruction uses the same CPU cycles count independently of its condition.

Comment: As you pointed out that ```jle``` and ```jl``` are same in terms of performance then ```a<=b``` should perform exactly similar in performance to ```a<b```. Right?

Comment: Yes, `jl`, `jle`, `je` and any other similar instructions (so called `jcc` instructions, where `cc` is condition code) have the same performance.

Comment: *However, in practice usually <= will be implemented exactly like call to < followed by call to == or vice versa.* -- A C++ programmer who has some smarts would write `a <= b` as `!(b < a)` and only needs to implement `<`, thus one call, not two calls.

Comment: @MateenKiani there **do** exists CPUs which have only `<` and only `==` comparison instructions, but most of the time the compiler is smart enough to turn `(a <= b)` into `!(b < a)` (as long as definition of `<=` in high level language makes it clear that this is equivalent) and use the single comparison instruction and branch in the other way to "negate" the result. But x86 has all of these cases covered by "cc" instructions, so on x86 there's no difference at all, unless you are programming in assembly and you want to reuse the result of comparison multiple times further down in the code..

Answer (score 4):

Taking your question literally, the answer is `O(1)` for both.

But assuming that you're more interested in the *execution time*, the answer depends on whether the code is interpreted of compiled. Any modern compiler will optimise them both to the same code. An interpreter will take twice as long doing both checks for the equals and greater-than cases since the first test will fail and it will need to test the second.

Comment: Actually in python the type of variables is dynamic, so I guess the comparison operator has first to evaluate the current types and decide if they can be compared and with what operator implementation. That's very likely lot more performance-costly operation than the final comparison. In this regard the `< OR ==` way may be atrocious to performance if the naive interpreter is running the script and check types twice. But I guess most of the modern python is run by some VM capable of "hotspot" JIT and keep types info pre-resolved ahead and cached? (I don't use python myself, so I'm not sure).

Comment: (I mean I like your answer, it says pretty much everything I would want to say, but you managed to be lot more brief ... I just find kinda ridiculous the OP asks about such detail, yet he tags it both C++ and python, which means like completely different galaxy with regard to this question, the C++ optimizer will turn this probably into 1-3 instructions of CPU but the programmer has to specify everything precisely, types, operators, implementation details... while python is designed with completely different goals and it's kinda pointless to even discuss such subtlety)

Comment: @Ped7g CPython (as the default Python implementation) does not do any JITting or pretty much any optimization at all. Even if you test with literals (static type) and don't use the result like in `for _ in range(10000): 2 <= 1` vs `for _ in range(10000): 2 < 1 or 2 == 1` you will get pretty much double the time for the latter (discounting the time for the iteration, i.e. `for _ in range(10000): pass`).

Comment: @uneven_mark wow... that's kinda sad from *my* point of view (of programmer dealing mostly with performance intensive tasks and data processing and micro optimizations)... then again, python is perfectly reasonable for many other tasks, but I did think its interpreter is more like Java VMs, if the language is so popular. Yet again I'm amazed by the actual power of current HW, if this kind of travesty is possible... :)

Comment: @Ped7g Usually, if Python is used for any computation-heavy task, all the inner computation loops are done in some builtin or module that is written in C or the like and compiled to native code and statically typed, either through some of the popular libraries (e.g. NumPy) or manually if you have special requirements (e.g. Python C API, SWIG, etc.). There are also additional modules/tools that compile or JIT (parts) of the Python code to native one  (e.g. Cython, numba, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Complexity is generally expressed in big-O notation. Even if the second case would be `O(2)` (compilers might disagree), then the complexities would still be the same because `O(2)` is exactly the same as `O(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Whether one takes twice as much as the other is irrelevant for complexity, they all have constant complexity, as independent of the value of `a` or `b` they take a fixed amount of operations.

In case you worry about performance, note that the compiler knows what expressions are equivalent and it is likely better than humans to pick the one that is cheapest.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the Time Complexity difference between "`a<=b`" and "`(a<b) OR (a==b)`"?

Complexity analysis applies to algorithms. Relational comparisons are not algorithms, so their complexity cannot be analysed. We can only analyse an algorithm used to implement such comparison. What algorithm can be used depends on what types are compared. The answer also depends on whether we consider worst, best or average case.

`<=` can **usually** be implemented as `(a<b) OR (a==b)`. In such case the complexity of `<=` cannot be worse than the complexity of `(a<b) OR (a==b)` unless it has been implemented sub-optimally. The complexity of `<=` is **usually** the same as the worse complexity of either `a<b` or `a==b`. Most often, all of these three have the same asymptotic complexity. But this depends on the type of the compared objects.

---

> ```
> int i =0; (i < 10) OR (i == 10)
> int i =0; i <= 10
> ```

The asymtotic complexity of these comparisons is exactly the same: It is constant. In fact, the size of `int` is constant for any system, so there is no input that can grow, and so asymptotic analysis would be pointless.